# Python timeit from command line - most functionality inside string not being timed

Tags: python, timeit

After looking around the forums and bit and tutorials on using timeit, I wasn't able to identify my problem but am sure I'm missing something major.

I'm trying to fun the following bit of code (modified slightly to just be an illustrative example) through timeit to time performance:

```
PREDS="
import numpy as np
from ML import fit, predict
from utils.data_transform import features_squared_only

red_features = np.load('data/red_features.npy')
f_sq2r = features_squared_only(red_features)
query_sn = np.load('data/query_sn.npy')
q_sq2r = features_squared_only(query_sn)
l4 = np.load('data/red_mlabels4.npy')
W = fit(f_sq2r, l4)
preds = predict(q_sq2r, W)"

python -m timeit -v -s "PREDS"
```

giving me this:

```
10 loops -> 5.11e-06 secs
100 loops -> 4.39e-06 secs
1000 loops -> 1.27e-05 secs
10000 loops -> 8.47e-05 secs
100000 loops -> 0.000769 secs
1000000 loops -> 0.00792 secs
10000000 loops -> 0.0854 secs
100000000 loops -> 0.804 secs
raw times: 0.822 0.791 0.808
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00791 usec per loop
```

However, this is definitely incorrect, as even:

```
python -m timeit -v -s "1+2"
```

gives results like

```
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00781 usec per loop
```

Not to mention, when I included print statements in that "PREDS" sequence of instructions above, it only appeared 8 times (there was also 10^8 'loops' - probably related?). Measuring that same code, excluding the imports, took about 5 seconds of wall clock time, so it seems unlikely anyway that other calls/etc. that may have been excluded by timeit if it actually timed all the code above would add up to ~4.2 seconds.

It seems pretty clear that most of my code is not actually being timed/tested, but I'm not sure what's missing to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `-s` option isn't doing what you think it is doing;  `s` signifies setup. So apparently you're only setting up your timer with some code, but you aren't actually timing *anything*.

> `-s S`, `--setup=S`
>
> statement to be executed once initially (default pass)

More so, using `"PREDS"` as a string is not also doing what you expect. I'll suggest you write a script for this and put the logic in it, rather than try to scramble everything into your terminal

Comment: You beat me to it. I went back to the example I thought I was copying from, then checked the docs and found that I wasn't using it correctly.